# Product modulo random numbers

Tags: c++, algorithm

A prime `p` is fixed. A sequence of n numbers is given, each from `1` to `p - 1`. It is known that the numbers in the sequence are chosen randomly, equally likely and independently from each other. Choose some numbers from the sequence so that their product, taken modulo `p`, is equal to the given number `x`. If no numbers are selected, the product is considered equal to one.

**Input:**

The first line contains three integers separated by spaces: the length of the sequence `n`, the prime number `p` and the desired value `x`

```
(n=100, 2<=p<=10^9, 0<x<p)
```

Next, `n` integers are written, separated by spaces or line breaks: the sequence `a1`, `a2`,. . ., `an`

```
(0 <ai <p)
```

**Output:**

Print the numbers from the sequence whose product modulo `p` is equal to `x`. The order in which numbers are displayed is not important. If there are several possible answers, print any of them

**Example:**

```
INPUT:

100 11 4
9 6 1 1 10 4 9 10 3 1 10 1 6 8 3 3 9 8
10 3 7 7 1 3 3 1 5 2 10 4 1 5 6 7 2 6
2 8 3 3 6 7 6 3 1 5 10 2 2 10 9 6 8 6
2 10 3 2 7 4 3 2 8 6 4 1 7 2 10 8 4 9
7 9 8 7 4 7 3 2 8 2 3 7 1 5 2 10 7 1 8
6 4 10 10 3 6 10 2 1

OUTPUT:
4 6 10 9
```

**My solution:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std; 

int main()
{
    int n,p,x,y,m,k,tmp; 

    vector<int> v;
    cin >> n >> p >> x;
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++){
        cin >> tmp;
        v.push_back(tmp);
    } 

    sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    v.erase(v.begin(), upper_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), 1));

    k=-1;
    while(1){
        k++;
        m = 1;
        y = x+p*k;;
        vector<int> res; 
        for (int i = 0; i<n; i++){ 
            if (y == 1) break;
            if ( y%v[i] == 0){
                res.push_back(v[i]);
                m*=v[i];
                m%=p;
                y = y/v[i];
            }
        } 
        if (m==x) {
            for (int i = 0; i<res.size(); i++){
                cout << res[i] << " ";
            }
            break;
        }

    } 

    return 0;
}
```

In my solution, I used condition (`y=x+k*p`, where `y` is the product of numbers in the answer, and `k` is some kind of natural number). And also iterated over the value `k`.

This solution sometimes goes beyond the allotted time. Please tell me a more correct algorithm.

[image]

Comment: For example: When your `y` is `18`, it will fail if there is at least 1 `2` and exactly 1 `3` in the list. In this case it would not look for `3*6` or `2*9`. So, your code does not find all cases.

Comment: I understand it. But the problem is that the whole concept of my solution is wrong. I need only an algorithm or some kind of hint.

Comment: I would start with `k=0`, instead of `k=p-1`. Also you excluded `k=0`, you stop at `k=1`. `4 % 11 == 4`, so a solution is `4`, e.g. whenever `x` is in the list, it is a solution.

Comment: Here, for the most part, the problem is that the algorithm takes too much time.

Comment: No, your first problem is that it gives wrong answers. What is the benefit of speed optimizing a program, which gives wrong answers?

Comment: I'm not talking about optimization, but about a completely different approach.

Comment: ok, I rewrote the code with brute force variable k. Now the code will always give the right solution. But it still takes too much time. And does not change the situation.

Comment: You still exclude `k=0`. What if `x` is a prime number and in the vector? You wouldn't find it and loop forever ==> TL

Comment: fixed, but the result is the same

Comment: How large can `n` be? Is it always 100?

Comment: The condition for the task says yes. Although this is strange because it is not clear why then input n

Comment: Can you please share a link to the online judge? (It would make it easier to confirm suggestions.)

Comment: unfortunately there is limited registration

Comment: Too bad you deleted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59608622/5459839). I spent a lot of time on it, and was close to posting an answer. :/ Is that question no longer relevant?

Answer (score 1):

I would consider a backtracking routine over the hashed multiset of the input list. Since `p` is a prime, at any point we can consider if the current multiple, `m`, has `(multiplicative_inverse(m, p) * x) % p` in our multiset (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_inverse). If it exists, we're done. Otherwise, try multiplying either by the same number we are currently visiting in the multiset, or by the next one (keep the result of the multiplication modulo `p`).

Please see comment below for a link to example code in Python. The example you gave has trivial solutions so it would be helpful to have some non-trivial, as well as challenging examples to test and refine on. Please also clarify if more than one number is expected in the output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic programming approach. It requires O(p) memory cells and O(p*n) loop iterations. There is possible several optimization (to exclude processing input duplicates, or print longest/shortest selection chain). Following is simplest and basic DP-program, demonstrating this approach.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int data[] = {
9, 6, 1, 1, 10, 4, 9, 10, 3, 1, 10, 1, 6, 8, 3, 3, 9, 8,
10, 3, 7, 7, 1, 3, 3, 1, 5, 2, 10, 4, 1, 5, 6, 7, 2, 6,
2, 8, 3, 3, 6, 7, 6, 3, 1, 5, 10, 2, 2, 10, 9, 6, 8, 6,
2, 10, 3, 2, 7, 4, 3, 2, 8, 6, 4, 1, 7, 2, 10, 8, 4, 9,
7, 9, 8, 7, 4, 7, 3, 2, 8, 2, 3, 7, 1, 5, 2, 10, 7, 1, 8,
6, 4, 10, 10, 3, 6, 10, 2, 1
};

struct elm {
  int val;  // Value
  int prev; // from which elemet we come to this
  int n;    // add loop cound for prevent multiple use same val
};

void printsol(int n, int p, int x, const int *in) {
  struct elm *dp = (struct elm *)calloc(p, sizeof(struct elm));
  int i, j;
  for(i = 0; i < n; i++) // add initial elements into DP array
    dp[in[i]].val = in[i];
  for(i = 0; i < n; i++) { // add elements, one by one, to DP array
    if(dp[in[i]].val <= 1) // skip secondary "1" multipliers
      continue;
    for(j = 1; j < p; j++) 
      if(dp[j].val != 0 && dp[j].n < i) {
        int y = ((long)j * in[i]) % p;
        dp[y].val  = in[i]; // current value, for printout
        dp[y].prev = j; // reference to prev element
        dp[y].n    = n; // loop num, for prevent double reuse
        if(x == y && dp[x].n > 0) {
          // targed reached - print result, by iterate linklist
          int mul = 1;
          while(x != 0) {
            printf(" %d ", dp[x].val);
            mul *= dp[x].val; mul %= p;
            x = dp[x].prev;
          }
          printf("; mul=%d\n", mul);
          free(dp);
          return;
        }
      } // for+if
  } // for i
  free(dp);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  printsol(100, 11, 4, data);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `O(p*n)` time and `O(p)` space?  How is this practical for `2 <= p <= 10^9`?

Comment: Max 16mb, I assume. with some optimization tricks - can be packed into 8. Also, if you have limits for "n" (input size), there is also can be added some optimization.

Comment: But aren't 100,000,000,000 or so iterations going to take too long (TLE)?

Comment: Yes, maybe. I do not know your limitations. Also, as I mentioned before, there is possible some optimizations - for example, do not proceed value, which does not produce new values in the DP-dataset. But, there is long thinking and coding, I demonstrated you approach, not solution for your requirements.