# Checking whether a line segment is in the camera field of view

Tags: python, c++, algorithm

Input data:

> Field size `H` from 10^3 to 10^6;
>
> Number of line segments `N` from 1 to 100;
>
> Camera angle `α` in radians from to 0.01 to 0.05;
>
> Starting angle of camera direction `D` (0/90/180/270 degrees);
>
> Coordinates of the camera `Xs, Ys`;
>
> The angle `β` from -2pi to 2pi, at which the camera should rotate.
>
> The location of all segments on the field and their colors;

**The program should display all the colors that the camera sees in order.**

For convenience, data can be visualized in this way:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_figwidth(10)  
fig.set_figheight(10)

ax = fig.gca()
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0, H+250, 250))
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0, H+250, 250))

plt.plot([0,H], [0,0], 'k')
plt.plot([0,0], [0,H], 'k')
plt.plot([0,H], [H,H], 'k')
plt.plot([H,H], [0,H], 'k')



for line in lines:  
    plt.plot([line[0],line[2]], [line[1],line[3]], '#'+line[4], linewidth=5)

ax.add_artist(plt.Circle((Xs, Ys), 100, color='r'))

plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

For example:

```
Input:
2000 5 0.01 (H, N, α)
0 875 625 1.22 (D, Xs, Ys, β)
1000 750 1000 1000 0000FF (X1,Y1,X2,Y2, Color)
750 1250 1250 1250 FFFF00 (X1,Y1,X2,Y2, Color)
1250 1000 1500 1000 FF0000 (X1,Y1,X2,Y2, Color)
1500 750 1250 750 00FF00 (X1,Y1,X2,Y2, Color)
1750 250 1750 750 0000FF (X1,Y1,X2,Y2, Color)

Output:
0000FF 00FF00 FF0000 0000FF
```

[image] 
One more example:

```
Input:
4000 12 0.01
270 1625 1125 6.28
1000 1750 1500 1750 00FF00
2250 1750 2000 1750 00FF00
1750 500 2250 500 00FF00
2250 1500 2250 2000 0000FF
1250 1500 1250 1250 0000FF
2750 2250 2750 2500 FFFF00
2750 1750 2750 750 FFFF00
2500 500 2500 1000 FF0000
2500 1750 2750 1750 FF0000
1000 750 1500 750 FF0000
750 1000 750 1500 FF0000
1000 750 1000 1250 FF0000

Output:
00FF00 FF0000 FFFF00 FF0000 0000FF 00FF00 0000FF FF0000
```

[image]

I tried two ways. In the [first method](https://pastebin.com/ETZfLmAu), I neglect the angle of view of the camera, and iterate over all degrees, checking for intersections with all lines. In the [second method](https://pastebin.com/HQqWPQTy), I compare the angles of all points relative to the horizon

But neither the first method nor the second work properly.

**Please tell me, the algorithm with which I can solve this problem**

Comment: Can you explain the input parameters a bit more? What is the effect of changing H? Does it represent a radius around the camera that is like a horizon, beyond which nothing can be seen? What does β mean? Does this parameter imply that the camera does not really rotate *continuously*, but rotates with instant "jumps", possibly skipping part of the scenery (when β > α)? Can the intersection point between two segments be such that it is no end-point of either segment, so that they truly cross each other?

Comment: H - a natural number that is divisible by 250 without a remainder. The borders of this square field are white. But this does not affect the task, since only the colors of the segments need to be printed in response.  β is the angle that the camera should turn around. If the angle is positive, then the camera rotates counterclockwise, if  β is less than zero, then the camera rotates clockwise. The camera rotates smoothly. Color segments do not intersect.

Comment: Here is an explanation for the first example. The numbers on the segments show the order of their printing. https://i.ibb.co/vHnqt9y/image.png

Comment: OK, so the value of H can be ignored, and only the sign of β is relevant, right?

Comment: Yes, and do not forget about the angle alpha is also important, this is the viewing angle of the camera itself.

Comment: For simplicity, α can be divided into two and shift the initial angle of the camera clockwise on it, and the final angle of the β, on the contrary, shift counterclockwise on it. Like this https://i.ibb.co/PG1xbhK/image.png

Comment: And yet, the coordinates of the camera can always be represented as: Xs = 125+250*T; Ys = 125+250*K where T and K is a natural numbers.

Comment: I miss the point of these angles. Now it seems like the magnitude of β is important. But I don't see how the angle α can influence the outcome, whether it is 0.1 or 0.4, ... I don't understand.

Comment: The angles α and β are indicated in radians. That is, in degrees, the angle α can be from 5.72958 to 28.6479.

Comment: I understand radians, but I don't see how varying α could influence the result. Or is the complete view angle defined by α+β?

Comment: Yes, the complete viewing angle is defined as α + β

Comment: there are no ideas?

Comment: Sure, I have ideas, but life is busy. I might still come with an answer.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/iBPh3vQ3 - my new way of solving, with translation into a spherical coordinate system. I think the algorithm will be clear from the code. But this algorithm is still far from perfect

Comment: What if the camera first sees blue, then nothing at all, and then again blue. Should the output be just once occurrence of blue, or two? Or should the "nothing" also be somehow represented in the output?